# Failing to sort my array with std::sort and custom comparator

Tags: c++, arrays, string, sorting, vector

```
arr.push_back("1"); 
arr.push_back("34"); 
arr.push_back("3"); 
arr.push_back("98"); 
arr.push_back("9"); 
arr.push_back("76"); 
arr.push_back("45"); 
arr.push_back("4"); 

sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), myCompare); 

//Here is the compare function
int myCompare(string X, string Y) 
{ 
  string XY = X.append(Y); 

  string YX = Y.append(X); 
  return XY.compare(YX) > 0 ? 1: 0; 
} 
//output should be 998764543431
```

I got some confusion regarding the sorting for eg. we have numbers `{"1","34","3","98","9","76","45","4"}`. When we first compare 2 strings we have 2 options `134` and `341` so as `341` is bigger we'll get `341` as a returned string.

Similarly, we get `3341` in next iteration and `983341` in next and `9983341` in next but when `76` arrives it has to be appended either at the beginning or at the end either it will `998334176` or `769983341` which is wrong. Am I missing something?

Comment: Looks like I am getting the answer you are expecting. How are you printing the resultant `arr`?

Comment: for (int i=0; i < arr.size() ; i++ ) 
        cout << arr[i]; 
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues. Ignoring the questions of why you're storing int as `std::string`? This only makes sense if you'll be storing non-integer data in the array at some point. Integer comparison is very fast. `string` comparison is slow and almost never produces the desired result.

First,

`std::string::append` modifies the parameter. So, if I have:

```
string x = "left";
string y = "right";
string xy = x.append(y);
```

`x` now equals "leftright", as does `xy`.  Your comparison function would append x to y, then y to the result.

Your method, called with X = 1, Y = 34:

```
string XY = X.append(Y); 
// XY = "134", X = "134", Y = "34"
string YX = Y.append(X); 
// YX = 34134, Y = "34134", X = "134"

return XY.compare(YX) > 0 ? 1: 0;
```

So, this could be expressed as

```
X = X + Y;
XY = X;
Y = Y + X;
YX = Y;
```

`string::compare` does a character compare. So, if your array were sorted just using `string::compare`, you'd get

```
1       3       34      4       45      76      9       98
```

Second,

> When we first compare 2 strings we have 2 options 134 and 341 so as
>   341 is bigger we'll get 341 as a returned string.

"341" *is* bigger than "134". However, you aren't comparing "341" with "134" - you're comparing "134" with "3134". "3134" is only bigger because it starts with a 3 instead of a "1". If the numbers were "1341" and "341", "341" would still be bigger.

If your goal is just to sort the list based on integer value,

```
int myCompare(string X, string Y)
{
    return atoi(X.c_str()) < atoi(Y.c_str());
}
```

Or, more sanely, use an int array instead of strings, and let `sort` use it's built-in comparison function.

Comment: why did you take x=1 and y=34? what if we are having this code                       bool comparator(int a, int b)
        {
            string a1 = to_string(a)+ to_string(b);
            string b1 = to_string(b)+ to_string(a);
            return a1>b1;
        }
        sort(nums.begin(),nums.end(),comparator);  and nums array is [3,30,34,5,9] then what would be the int a and int b? and how are we going to change them in each iteration?

Comment: @sunidhichaudhary because they were the first two elements in your example. they get compared at some point, as good as any other pair.

Comment: I am confused about how the comparator function is working.

Comment: @sunidhichaudhary okay. Could you elaborate on "confused?" The comparator is called repeatedly - somewhere between (approximately) O(n^2) and O(n log n) times - for different pairs of values in the source. The order has very little to do with the sorted-ness of the original array, and it won't be called in the order of elements in the source array except for very unusual circumstances.

`std::sort` typically uses quicksort, (though I believe that is implementation-dependent, according to the spec) so google that. Set breakpoints, step through and see what’s really happening.

Comment: okay, means that the comparator is called for every possible pair in the array and it will check every possibility?

Comment: @sunidhichaudhary Potentially, but not necessarily. Any sort that worked that way would always be O(n^2), in which case we'd all use bubblesort because it's simple, or work 20 hour days because we're waiting on a page to refresh. Either go read about quicksort (and 400 other sort algorithms), or stop relying on the comparison order, let the built-in sort do its thing, THEN build whatever output it is that you wanted by concatenating the sorted result. Good luck.

Comment: Okay, I got it. Thanks